# Integrating information from two lists by values in first in R

Tags: r, list, merge, bioinformatics

I need some help integrating information from two lists in R.

I have a list of haplotype codes named `haps`. These represent windows in which a haplotype is present (1-6).

```
`1`
[1] 19 31 31 31 31

$`2`
[1]  7 31 31 31 31

$`3`
[1] 15 31 31 31 31

$`4`
[1] 31 31 31 31 31

$`5`
[1] 31 31 31 31 31

$`6`
[1] 30 31 31 31 31
```

I have a second list representing metadata for those haplotypes called `ls`. Each element corresponds to its counterpart in the above list, so `haps[[1]][1] = 19` has a corresponding ls of `ls[[1]][1] = 2`.

```
$`1`
[1] 2 0 2 3 4

$`2`
[1] 2 0 2 3 4

$`3`
[1] 2 0 2 3 4

$`4`
[1] 2 0 2 3 4

$`5`
[1] 2 0 2 3 4

$`6`
[1] 2 0 2 3 4
```

I want to get a final list for each window containing the counts of each of the haplotypes and the total ls for each one, such as:

```
$`1`
  haplotype count ls
1        19     1   2
2        31     4   9

$`2`
  haplotype count ls
1         7     1   2
2        31     4   9

$`3`
  haplotype count ls
1        15     1   2
2        31     4   9

$`4`
  haplotype count ls
1        31     5   11

$`5`
  haplotype count ls
1        31     5   11

$`6`
  haplotype count ls
1        30     1   2
2        31     4   9
```

I am able to implement the counting step using the following code:

```
counting <- function(x,y) {
  u <- unique(x);
  data.frame(
    haplotype=u,
    count=sapply(u, function(v) { length(which(x==v)) } )
  )
}

counts = lapply(haps, counting)
```

But am having trouble how to total ls for specific values. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may require `Map/mapply` from `base R`

```
Map(function(u, v) 
    {
     # get the frequency count from hap element with table
      # convert to data.frame
       dat <- as.data.frame(table(u))
         # sum of ls element by hap element
         dat$ls <- rowsum(v, u)[,1]
        # rename the columns
       names(dat)[1:2] <- c("haplotype", "count")
      # return the dataset 
     dat
     }, haps, ls)
```

---

Or use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(haps, ls, ~ 
       # create a tibble from the elements of haps, ls
       tibble(haplotype = .x, ls = .y) %>% 
         # do a group by haplotype
            group_by(haplotype) %>% 
           # summarise by taking the count (n())
          # sum of ls
         summarise(count = n(), ls = sum(ls), .groups = 'drop')
  )
```